# Bootstrap Submenu showing up before hovered over?

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, submenu

I have a site where I've altered the bootstrap nav bar slightly so that it will be hoverable until it's viewed on mobile and then it's clickable. I just added a submenu within the dropdown and for some reason when I hover over the parent/main nav the dropdown appears and the submenu will appear as well before I've hovered over it's parent element. Can anyone figure out why this is happening or offer another way to do this? Below is what it looks like when I scroll over the main Administrator link and haven't hovered over the Page 1-1 submenu. Thanks!

[image]

Example of one of the menu items

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Administor</a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li class="dropdown-submenu">
              <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Page 1-1</a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Page 1-1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Page 1-2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Page 1-3</a></li>
                </ul>               
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Submenu 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Submenu 2</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
   </ul>
</div></nav>
```

Comment: please show your css also or fiddle link or working demo then it will be easier to find solution

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/kennakins/snmbxaLa/ So I got it working fine on click, but I'd like to be able to have it open on Hover and then be able to open on Click when in mobile. :-/

Answer (score 0):

Please add this code on css. hope it will be useful for you

```css
@media screen and (min-width: 768px){
    .dropdown:hover > .dropdown-menu{display: block !important;}
}
```